# ri_cal issue with feed generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icalendar

I have the following setup to generate out an iCal feed, when our digital signage boxes subscribe to the feed at http://foo/rooms/foo/feed.ics they pull in the event information ok, but don't stop displaying the event. I believe this is because the actual ical file generated by the below function puts the dtend before dtstart. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
def feed
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  @events = @room.events
  respond_to do |format|
    if @room.valid?
      format.ics { render :text => self.generate_ical }
    else
      format.ics { render :nothing => true, :status => :forbidden}
    end
  end
end

def generate_ical
  RiCal.Calendar do |ical|
    ical.add_x_property 'X-WR-CALNAME',@room.name
    @events.each do |e|
      ical.event do |event|
        event.dtstart = e.start
        event.dtend = e.end
        event.summary = e.summary
      end
    end
  end.export
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is with the feed reader, not the feed generator. The iCal standard does not impose any ordering of properties within an iCalendar object.

Comment: Im well aware this is late but thanks so much for your answer!